# mysql between and used via JDBC preparedstatement - getting Parameter index out of range exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

From the select query parameterized the value (date value with BETWEEN , AND)

my query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS assignedtotalcount FROM ticket, ticket_data
WHERE ticket.`ticket_id` = ticket_data.`ticket_id`
AND ticket.`created` BETWEEN '?' AND '?'
```

from the above query parameterized the values in BETWEEN , AND

Java code

```
static String dateFrom = "2018-01-01";
static String dateTo = "2018-01-31";
String query = reportQuery.toString();
statement = connection.createStatement();
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, dateFrom);
preparedStatement.setString(2, dateTo);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
```

while execute i am getting the below exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

please help me to resolved

Comment: As an aside, prefer to pass objects rather than strings to the query. `LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.JANUARY, 1);` and then `preparedStatement.setObject(1, dateFrom);`, etc.

Comment: By the way, as another comment said, pass smart objects not dumb strings with JDBC 4.2 and later: `myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , LocalDate.parse( “2018-01-31” ) ) ;`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362660/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-w?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). While using PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362660/java-sql-sqlexception-parameter-index-out-of-range-1-number-of-parameters-w)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not quote the placeholders. You need to change the `'?'` to `?`.

So the query become like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS assignedtotalcount FROM ticket, ticket_data
WHERE ticket.`ticket_id` = ticket_data.`ticket_id`
AND ticket.`created` BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: you're welcome could you please mark the question as solved